# Lenovo ThinkStation P310 headless AMT/KVM

Tags: vnc, intel, amt, vpro, lenovo

```
Model:30AT0054PB (ThinkStation P310)
SN: S4AM6910
BIOS rev: FWKT80A
ME Firmware rev: 11.0.27.3000
```

Has anybody have any success with running VNC via KVM/AMT connection to P310 in headless mode (without monitor)?

BIOS and Intel ME Firmware updated.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In my situation as soon as I disconnect VGA cable, the vnc client disconnects with error:

```
Error 0x80862000. Unsupported or inactive display adapter.
```

After cable reconnection the display in the client come back almost instantly.

It seems, that there's a bug in power management code.

[dmidecode - detailed hardware specification](https://pastebin.com/VkiqcaEX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenovo staff member confirmed that it is a bug. It looks like Lenovo plans some BIOS update in the near future:

[image: lenovo thread]

[Source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/P310-headless-AMT-KVM/td-p/3851004)